# CSS offset in Bootstrap-like grid

Tags: html, css, grid, margin

I'm trying to recreate [Bootstrap's offset](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting) in its desktop grid whereby a class like `.col-md-offset-3` creates an offset via `margin-left` .

For some reason, in [my attempt](http://codepen.io/nathanbweb/pen/emMrvE?editors=110), this CSS selector fails (i.e. the div is not offset):

```
.col-offset-8 {margin-left ... }
```

But both of these succeed:

```
div.col-offset-8 {margin-left ... }

col-4.col-offset-8 {margin-left ... } /*note: multiple class selectors, no space */
```

Why won't `.col-offset-8` work by itself?

[Here's my CodePen](http://codepen.io/nathanbweb/pen/emMrvE?editors=110).

```css
@media all and (min-width:760px) {
  .row {margin:0 auto;overflow:hidden;}
  .row > div {margin:10px;overflow:hidden;float:left;display:inline-block;}
  .row {width:960px;}
  .col-8 {width:620px} .col-4 {width:300px}
  .col-12 {width:940px} .col-6 {width:460px}
  .col-offset-8 {
    margin-left:650px; /* = col-8 + margins */
  }
}

/* for demo */
.row {background:#ccc}
.row > div {background:#eee; outline:1px solid #444}
p {font:24px/60px Arial;color:#000;text-align:center}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <p>col-12</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4 col-offset-8">
    <p>col-4 offset-8</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-8">
    <p>col-8</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <p>col-4</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <p>col-12</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because the selector `.row > div` is [more specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than `.col-offset-8`.

More precisely, `.row > div` has a specifity value of 11 whereas `.col-offset-8` has a value of 10.

Because of this, the `margin: 10px` from `.row > div` is overwriting the `margin-left`

You could [increase the specifcity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of your selector from `.col-offset-8` to `.row .col-offset-8`. In doing to `margin-left` will overwrite `margin: 10px`.

[**Updated Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/radraB)

```
.row .col-offset-8 {
  margin-left: 650px; /* = col-8 + margins */
}
```

For what it's worth, [this is a nice tool](http://specificity.keegan.st/) for calculating specificity.